# Dealing with food craving

Tags: karma, food

During sleeping I experience strong food urges.. luckily I am most of the time aware of these acts but I still usually eat something but less (which is an accomplishment). It happened today again and before eating I rehearsed internally "I am the owner of my actions,heir to my actions..." which switched my focus more to a long term perspective because I knew that I would perpetuate a craving so I better tolerate the pain now then to go the old pathway which would maintain the kamma..

Now any recommendations what I could do? I think I have to meditate more on the disadvantages / short nature of food and even on the kamma thing (which is important anyways to keep in mind). Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22852/471) about a [video talk](https://youtu.be/W5Lg9P-VekA) by [Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu](http://buddhistinsights.com/yuttadhammo-bhikkhu/) on addiction to pornography and addiction in general. That answer also states:

> The other technique he proposes is to watch your mind for triggers and
>   observe how lust arises in the mind and recognize it (basically
>   insight meditation). You can find more info on this in his chapter
>   entitled "[Daily Life](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-six-daily-life/)" of his booklet "[How To Meditate](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/)".

I would say that the same technique could be applied to food craving as well.

The [Donapaka Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.013.olen.html) may also be helpful for the case of gluttony:

> Once when the Buddha was living at Savatthi, King Pasenadi of Kosala
>   ate a whole bucketful of food, and then approached the Buddha,
>   engorged and panting, and sat down to one side. The Buddha, discerning
>   that King Pasenadi was engorged and panting, took the occasion to
>   utter this verse:
>
> **When a person is constantly mindful,
>
>   And knows when enough food has been taken,
>
>   All their afflictions become more slender
>
>   — They age more gradually, protecting their lives.**
>
> Now at that time the brahman youth Sudassana was standing nearby, and
>   King Pasenadi of Kosala addressed him: "Come now, my dear Sudassana,
>   and having thoroughly mastered this verse in the presence of the
>   Buddha, recite it whenever food is brought to me. And I will set up
>   for you a permanent offering of a hundred kahaapanas every day." "So
>   be it, your majesty," the brahman youth Sudassana replied to the king.
>
> Then King Pasenadi of Kosala gradually settled down to [eating] no
>   more than a cup-full of rice. At a later time, when his body had
>   become quite slim, King Pasenadi stroked his limbs with his hand and
>   took the occasion to utter this utterance:
>
> Indeed the Buddha has shown me
>   Compassion in two different ways:
>   For my welfare right here and now,
>   and also for in the future.

Comment: You may be right but food is a special case, unlike other addictions -- a cure (or desirable outcome) for drug addiction, for example, is a complete abstinence, cutting off; whereas for food, it may be something more like, smaller portions, regular times, and healthier (e.g. lower-calorie) stuffs.

Comment: @ChrisW I've added the Donapaka Sutta which fits this (smaller portions).